# reading a big xls file into R

Tags: excel, r, import

I have an excel file with ~10000 rows and ~250 columns, currently I am using RODBC to do the importing:

```
channel <- odbcConnectExcel(xls.file="s:/demo.xls")
demo <- sqlFetch(channel,"Sheet_1")
odbcClose(channel)
```

But this way is a bit slow (I need a minute or two to import them), and the excel is originally encrypted, I need to remove the password to work on it, which is something that I prefer not to, I wonder if there is any better way (i.e. import faster, and capable of importing encrypted excel files)

Thanks.

Comment: At the very least [this](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html#Reading-Excel-spreadsheets) is a place you can go to read about different options.

Comment: Also consider the options at http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:data-io:ms_windows&s=excel (unfortunately I can't find the word "password" or "encrypted" anywhere in the document).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to try using the `XLConnect` package instead of `RODBC`.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html

Comment: Why? Can you demonstrate that it's faster for a problem of this scale, or that it solves the encryption problem?

Comment: My bad... XLConnect takes about the same time as RODBC + there seemingly is no way to handle encrypted files.